# Feedback link on Meta Stack Exchange should be removed

Tags: feature-request, meta, per-site-meta, feedback, footer

Feedback link in the footer of MSE refers to the same page, i.e. to MSE itself.

> [image: mse feedback]

Other sites have such link only for main versions, but not for the per-site metas. I think this link should be removed from MSE to be consistent with other meta sites.

Comment: It is a bit of a circular reference isn't it? Unless we added a meta.meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Mgetz your comment helps me to find [another bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310257/339911).

Answer (score 4):

No, that link can stay for consistency sake.

If it went to a dead-end I would agree but as it links back to the Meta it self there is no issue as feedback about Meta should be posted on Meta.

Once Twitter explodes due to complaints it is earlier enough to reconsider.

Comment: Yep, no reason to remove it.

Comment: @JoeFriend should the question be tagged [status-declined] then?

Answer (score 4):

> If it went to a dead-end I would agree but as it links back to the Meta it self there is no issue as feedback about Meta should be posted on Meta

There is an issue: It is very confusing for people to click on a link to just land on the same page (or the main page).

People click on 'feedback' with a certain expectation. For instance, they might be expecting to get some feedback form where they can send a message to Jeff and Joel how great their website is.

It can be some other reason why people click on 'feedback', but it is very unlikely that people click on the link 'feedback' just to get back to the main page (people expect some function is instead).

So, that feedback link is confusing because it doesn't do anything (it goes back to the same page, or the main page, which is not the user's expectation and much like a dead end).

---

Underlying this question is a [different issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369911/why-does-the-feedback-link-go-to-meta) and that is whether that link 'feedback' should be actually called 'feedback'.

Possibly the name 'meta' is better. This is also the way it is done on the mobile web page. (And going back to the superfluous addition of feedback link, on the mobile page the link to 'meta' is removed on meta.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I have to think a little bit about websites that are under construction that are full of links that just direct back to the main page because the actual page has not been developed yet. Those links that 'do not do anything or just send you to the main page' are extremely annoying. It makes you wonder whether something is wrong with the website (e.g. another reason for self referencing links is that the link is actually supposed to trigger some JavaScript. But the JavaScript might be broken)