# Overlapped Stack Exchange sites for non-existing site

Tags: bug, design, 404-not-found

The footer for a non-existing site, e.g. [xxx.stackexchange.com](http://xxx.stackexchange.com/), contains overlapped text:

> [image: Overlapped]

Is this behavior intentional?