# Bottom banner not showing link to meta

Tags: support, per-site-meta, navigation, footer

**On my phone** I get in the bottom a link to the meta page of the website

**On my desktop** (Ubuntu with Firefox) I do not get this link.

This makes it more difficult to navigate. Do I miss something, or is this a bug?

(Edit: As Glorfindel explains in his answer it is not a bug but intentional. However, it might still be something that needs change. This nonuniform look between phone/desktop sites is confusing)

#### Screenshot on my phone

[image: bottom banner phone]

#### Screenshot on my desktop

[image: bottom banner desktop]

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369911/why-does-the-feedback-link-go-to-meta

Comment: @RockApe That's interesting. I am voting to close my own question with your link and it doesn't close it.

Comment: I see now. I voted to close it as duplicate. And a bit later I got the message like 'somebody (which was me) voted to close your question, does this answer your question' on which I can answer yes/no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Desktop site, the link has a different name, **Feedback**:

[image]

This issue is already discussed here: [Why does the "feedback" link go to Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369911/why-does-the-feedback-link-go-to-meta)

Comment: Thanks, that explains it and solves my problem with navigating. But I am not sure I should accept the answer. It is not a bug, but it is still a site feature that might be updated for others with the same problem that do not pass along this question and its answer.