# Rename "Feedback" to "Meta" in footer

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, footer

This post might not be relevant to MSE, but it is relevant to sites in the network.

The Feedback link in the footer directs us to child meta. I am glad about this. But, I feel the word "Feedback" gives new users the wrong impression and it would be better if it is renamed to "Meta".

[image: Screenshot of part of footer of Ask Ubuntu]

Renaming the word might also be helpful in increasing participation in child meta.

Comment: Do new users even know what meta is? Most likely not

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369911/why-does-the-feedback-link-at-the-bottom-of-a-stack-exchange-site-go-to-that-s

Comment: @charlietfl Well, they can learn what meta is from the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).